# Beautifulsoup Remove Tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm running this code in order to scrape zip codes from a website using BS4.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://example.com"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs each zip code
zip_code = page_soup.findAll("span",{"itemprop":"postalCode"})

print(zip_code)
```

I end up with this code, which is just a list of spans. Each span contains the zip code that I need.

```
[<span itemprop="postalCode">03257</span>, <span 
itemprop="postalCode">34240</span>, <span 
itemprop="postalCode">84660</span>, <span 
itemprop="postalCode">07717</span>]
```

However, I cannot figure out how to remove everything BUT the zip code that is in between the span tags. The goal is to end up with a list of zip codes only.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

To get only the text from a tag, use `tag.text`:

```
zip_codes = page_soup.find_all("span", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
zip_codes = [tag.text for tag in zip_codes]

print(zip_codes) # ['03257', '34240', '84660', '07717']
```